# R: 'write' call in Fortran gives NOTE when running R CMD check

Tags: r, fortran

I have quite successfully implemented an R package with some Fortran functions. Some of these functions needs to write to files, so naturally I use the Fortran statement `write(unit, fmt) var`.

When running R CMD check on the compiled package, it spits out the following NOTE:

```
checking compiled code ... NOTE
File 'Siccuracy/libs/i386/Siccuracy.dll':
  Found '_gfortran_st_write', possibly from 'write' (Fortran), 'print'
    (Fortran)
    Objects: 'dip.o', 'chips.o', 'link.o'
File 'Siccuracy/libs/x64/Siccuracy.dll':
  Found '_gfortran_st_write', possibly from 'write' (Fortran), 'print'
    (Fortran)
    Objects: 'dip.o', 'chips.o', 'link.o'

Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor the system RNG.
```

By removing the `write` calls one-by-one from dip.f95, I found that only when removing *all* `write` calls, did the note disappear (for that file at least).
Note that I

I am using the `write` calls for two different things: 1) Writing to flat text files, combinations of both integers and real values, and 2) Using `write` to convert an integer to a character by doing `write(char, *) int`.

Do I have options here to avoid this NOTE from R CMD check?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should use `iostat=` to avoid the possible termination.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VladimirF; I am already using `iostat=` most of the time... Adding `iostat=` and `err=` to all `write` calls did not resolve the issue.

Comment: No, it won't resolve. I actually assume there is no way to silence the NOTE, but my knowledge of R CMD is almost zero.